# OCaml type-directed API search

Tags: ide, ocaml

Is there a type-directed search tool in OCaml (like Coq's `SearchPattern` command) where I can define a type constraint, e.g. `_ * int -> float`, and then the tool will search a given set of files for "all functions mapping pairs whose second element is an integer to floats"?

Either a stand-alone tool, or something integrated into an IDE would be fine. The idea is that, when exploring a new API, if I want for instance to obtain a value of type `Foo.t`, looking for all functions of the form `_ -> Foo.t` might be more efficient than browing the entire API.

[Merlin](http://the-lambda-church.github.io/merlin/) helps finding the type of given expressions, but it has no such "API discovery" functions, as far as I know.

I found [OcamlScope](http://ocamloscope.herokuapp.com/), but it seems to be a web-only service, and restricted to a set of fixed libraries. I wanted to be able to search my own files for existing functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ocamloscope`'s source can be found here https://github.com/camlspotter/ocamloscope/. You may succeed to use it locally. There's even an [issue](https://github.com/camlspotter/ocamloscope/issues/17) for making an OPAM package out of it.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to be what I'm looking for. I still didn't succeed in compiling and using it locally, but it does seem to be the right tool.